# How to randomly divide a huge corpus into 3?

Tags: gate

I have a corpus(held in a JSerial Datastore) of thousands of documents with annotations. Now I need to divide it into 3 smaller ones, with random picking. What is the easiest way in GATE?

a piece of running code or detailed guide will be most welcomed!

Comment: Is this a corpus held in a serial datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Groovy console for this (load the "Groovy" plugin, then start the console from the Tools menu).

The following code assumes that

- you have opened the datastore in GATE developer
- you have loaded the source corpus, and its name is "fullCorpus"
- you have created three (or however many you need) other empty corpora *and saved them (empty) to the same datastore*.  These will receive the partitions
- you have no other corpora open in GATE developer apart from these four
- you have no documents open

Then you can run the following in the Groovy console:

```groovy
def rnd = new Random()

def fullCorpus = corpora.find { it.name == 'fullCorpus' }
def parts = corpora.findAll {it.name != 'fullCorpus' }

fullCorpus.each { doc ->
  def targetCorpus = parts[rnd.nextInt(parts.size())]
  targetCorpus.add(doc)
  targetCorpus.unloadDocument(doc)
}

return null
```

The way this works is to iterate over the documents and pick a corpus at random for each document to be added to.  The target sub-corpora should end up roughly (but not necessarily exactly) the same size.

The script does not save the final sub-corpora, so if it messes up you can just close them and then re-open them (empty) from the original datastore, the fix and re-run the script.  Once you're happy with the final result, right click on each sub-corpus in turn in the left hand tree and "save to its datastore" to write it all to disk.

Comment: Thank you so much Ian, this is Perfekt!